# Service host: Network service; High CPU usage

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8.1, cpu

Here is the offending service:

[image]

It will go up to 27% while browsing pages on chrome, just while loading, stops a few seconds afterwards. But between chrome and this, my CPU usage sometimes during these times goes up to upwards of 50, 80, even 100%.

Screenshot of some specs and temps to show my PC is fine and not throttling:

[image]

```
Windows 8.1
Chrome 48
AMD FX 8350
```

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK and also works for Win8.1: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select "First Level", under  Resource select **CPU usage** and click on **start**. Now capture 1 minute of the CPU usage. After 1 minute click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file (+ NGENPDB folder) into 1 zip, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.